# Tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'd like to write a function that combines a unique-name in list `u` with a verb in list `v` with another unique-name in u so that i'd get 3 outputs like this:

```
[ ("fluffy", "loves", "monkey"), ("bunny", "feeds", "fluffy"), 
  ("bunny", "feeds", "monkey") ]
```

The only thing is I don't know how to get it so that the second unique-name it gives me is different than the first. Here's my code:

```
let fun = [ u ++ " " ++ v ++ " " ++ u | u <- ["fluffy", "bunny", "monkey"], v <- ["eats", "feeds", "loves"]]
let funThree = take 3 (cycle fun)
```

Currently my output is this:

```
["fluffy eats fluffy","fluffy feeds fluffy","fluffy loves fluffy"]
```

Comment: no, i want three outputs only, i want it to take a name from u, combine it with a verb in v and combine that with a DIFFERENT name from u.

Comment: In the unfortunately deleted answer, the author was assuming you actually constructed a tuple like you indicate in the title and example. To do so you'd change the expression for the result of the list comprehension from e.g. `u1 ++ " " ++ v ++ " " ++ u2` to `(u1, v, u2)`. The first of those has the type `[Char]` while the second one has the type `([Char], [Char], [Char])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's define the names so we can use them more than once

```
> let names = ["fluffy", "bunny", "monkey"]
```

We can use `names` twice in a list comprehension, once to get the first unique-name `u1`, and again to get a second name, `u2`.

```
> let fun = [ u1 ++ " " ++ v ++ " " ++ u2 | u1 <- names, v <- ["eats", "feeds", "loves"], u2 <- names]
```

This results in 27 different strings

```
> fun
["fluffy eats fluffy","fluffy eats bunny","fluffy eats monkey","fluffy feeds fluffy","fluffy feeds bunny","fluffy feeds monkey","bunny eats fluffy","bunny eats bunny","bunny eats monkey","bunny feeds fluffy","bunny feeds bunny","bunny feeds monkey","monkey eats fluffy","monkey eats bunny","monkey eats monkey","monkey feeds fluffy","monkey feeds bunny","monkey feeds monkey"]
```

If `"fluffy eats fluffy"` is a little too wierd, we can make sure the two names are different by adding a condition, `u1 /= u2`.

```
> let fun = [ u1 ++ " " ++ v ++ " " ++ u2 | u1 <- names, v <- ["eats", "feeds", "loves"], u2 <- names, u1 /= u2]
```

This results in only 18 different strings.

```
> fun
["fluffy eats bunny","fluffy eats monkey","fluffy feeds bunny","fluffy feeds monkey","bunny eats fluffy","bunny eats monkey","bunny feeds fluffy","bunny feeds monkey","monkey eats fluffy","monkey eats bunny","monkey feeds fluffy","monkey feeds bunny"]
```